# How to find a closed-form expression for this integral depending on parameter?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

In 14.0 under Windows 10 I try to find the improper integral
$$\int\limits_{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\psi }}}^{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-\psi }}}
\frac{1}{r^2 \sqrt{-r^4+2 r^2-\psi }}\,dr$$
under the assumptions $\psi >0\land \psi <1$.

Unfortunately,

```
Integrate[1/r^2/Sqrt[2 r^2 - r^4 - \[Psi]], {r, Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]], 
Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]]},  Assumptions -> \[Psi] > 0 && \[Psi] < 1]
```

returns the input as well as

```
\[Psi] = 1/n; Integrate[1/r^2/Sqrt[2 r^2 - r^4 - \[Psi]], {r, Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]], 
Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]]}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

For many rational values of `\[Psi]`(for example, 2/3,1/3,1/7,...) Mathematica
calculates this integral.
However, it is difficult to derive the general formula from those values.

The numerical value

```
f[\[Psi]_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ 1/r^2/Sqrt[2 r^2 - r^4 - \[Psi]], 
{r, Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]], Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]]}]
Plot[f[\[Psi]], {\[Psi], 0, 1}]
```

[image]

says nothing about the rate of the growth of `f[\[Psi]]` as `\[Psi]` tends to zero from above.
Concerning `\[Psi]` tends to `1`, the result of

```
\[Psi] = 0.99900000000000000000000000000; 
NIntegrate[1/r^2/Sqrt[2 r^2 - r^4 - \[Psi]], {r, Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]],  Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]]}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> `1.5722703994037859370`

suggests this equals `Pi/2`.

I also try to find an antiderivative by

```
ad = Integrate[1/r^2/Sqrt[2 r^2 - r^4 - \[Psi]], r, 
Assumptions -> \[Psi] > 0 && \[Psi] < 1, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `(-((-2 r^2 + r^4 + \[Psi])/r) + (1/Sqrt[(1/(-1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]))]) I Sqrt[1 - r^2/( 1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])] (1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]) Sqrt[(-1 + r^2 +  Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])/(-1 + Sqrt[ 1 - \[Psi]])] (EllipticE[ I ArcSinh[r Sqrt[1/(-1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])]], ( 1 - Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])] -  EllipticF[I ArcSinh[r Sqrt[1/(-1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])]], ( 1 - Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])]))/(Sqrt[ 2 r^2 - r^4 - \[Psi]] \[Psi])`

Rubi produces the same result in a simpler form:

```
Get["Rubi`"]
adRubi = Int[1/r^2/Sqrt[2 r^2 - r^4 - \[Psi]], r]
Plot3D[Re[adRubi - ad], {r, 0, 1}, {\[Psi], 0, 1}]
```

Both results are doubtful in view of

```
u = ad /. r -> Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]];
l = ad /. r -> Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]];
FullSimplify[u - l, Assumptions -> \[Psi] > 0 && \[Psi] < 1]
```

> `Indeterminate`

and

```
u - l /. \[Psi] -> 0.5
```

> `Indeterminate`

The command

```
ClearAll[\[Psi]]; Limit[ad, r -> Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]], 
 Direction -> "FromBelow", Assumptions -> \[Psi] > 0 && \[Psi] < 1]
```

is running without any response for a long time.

So is it possible to find a closed-form expression for the integral under consideration with Mathematica?
PS. Maple 2023 answers
$$ \frac{\left(1-\sqrt{1-\psi}\right) \mathrm{EllipticE}\! \left(\sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1-\psi}}{1+\sqrt{1-\psi}}}\right)}{\psi  \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-\psi}}\, \left(1-\frac{2 \sqrt{1-\psi}}{1+\sqrt{1-\psi}}\right)}$$

Comment: Elliptic functions in the possible answer are allowed.

Comment: Maple 2023 answers $$ \frac{\left(1-\sqrt{1-\psi}\right) \mathrm{EllipticE}\! \left(\sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1-\psi}}{1+\sqrt{1-\psi}}}\right)}{\psi  \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-\psi}}\, \left(1-\frac{2 \sqrt{1-\psi}}{1+\sqrt{1-\psi}}\right)}$$ which is confirmed by numerics.

Comment: Since you now know what the correct answer is supposed to be, please include it in the question (it doesn't really belong in the comment) :)

Comment: @Domen: It is done.

Comment: The Maple's result implies the asymptotic $\sqrt{2}\, \psi^{-1}+\sqrt{2}\, \left(\frac{3 \ln\! \left(2\right)}{8}-\frac{\ln\! \left(\psi \right)}{16}-\frac{1}{16}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}$ as $\psi\to 0+$.

Comment: this may be further simplified to (Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]]/\[Psi])*
 EllipticE[(2*Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])/(1 + Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]])] where the argument of EllipticE is squared (Mathematica convention)

Comment: @Andreas: Many thanks for your valuable comment. Indeed, MMA"s [EllipticE](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html?q=EllipticE) differs from Maple's [one](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=EllipticE).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A change of variables can help:

```
integrand = 1/r^2/Sqrt[2  r^2 - r^4 - ψ];

i2 = 
 IntegrateChangeVariables[
   Inactive[Integrate][
     integrand, 
     {r, Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - ψ]], Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - ψ]]}
    ], 
   s, 
   s == r^2 - 1, 
   Assumptions -> ψ > 0 && ψ < 1
  ]

(*Inactive[Integrate][1/(
 2 (1 + s)^(3/2) Sqrt[1 - s^2 - ψ]), {s, -Sqrt[1 - ψ], Sqrt[
  1 - ψ]}]*)

i3=Integrate[i2[[1]], i2[[2]], Assumptions -> ψ > 0 && ψ < 1]
(* (1/(2 ψ))(Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - ψ]]
    EllipticE[(2 (-1 - Sqrt[1 - ψ] + ψ))/ψ] + 
  Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - ψ]]
    EllipticE[(2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - ψ] + ψ))/ψ]) *)
```

$$
\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\psi }} E\left(\frac{2 \left(\psi
   -\sqrt{1-\psi }-1\right)}{\psi }\right)+\sqrt{\sqrt{1-\psi
   }+1} E\left(\frac{2 \left(\psi +\sqrt{1-\psi }-1\right)}{\psi
   }\right)}{2 \psi }
$$

A brief numeric test seems to support this result:

```
Table[i3, {ψ, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}]
(* {14.4606, 7.33593, 4.94922, 3.75053, 3.02835, 2.54501, \
2.19849, 1.93769, 1.73415} *)

Table[NIntegrate[integrand,
  {r, Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 - ψ]], 
   Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - ψ]]}], {ψ, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}]
(* {14.4606, 7.33593, 4.94922, 3.75053, 3.02835, 2.54501, \
2.19849, 1.93769, 1.73415} *)
```

Also

```
Limit[i3, ψ -> 1]
(* π/2 *)
```

Comment: Also `Series[(1/(2  \[Psi])) (Sqrt[
      1 - Sqrt[
        1 - \[Psi]]]  EllipticE[(2  (-1 - 
           Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]] + \[Psi]))/\[Psi]] + 
    Sqrt[1 + 
       Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]]]  EllipticE[(2  (-1 + 
           Sqrt[1 - \[Psi]] + \[Psi]))/\[Psi]]), {\[Psi], 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> \[Psi] > 0 && \[Psi] < 1]` results in `Sqrt[2]/\[Psi]+(-3+4 Log[2]+Log[4]-Log[\[Psi]])/(8 Sqrt[2])+((-109+120 Log[2]+30 Log[4]-30 Log[\[Psi]]) \[Psi])/(512 Sqrt[2])+O[\[Psi]]^(3/2)`